# AWS Parameters and Secrets Lambda Extension behaviour

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-secrets-manager, aws-lambda-layers

When retrieving secrets using the AWS Parameters and Secrets Lambda Extension, does the cache get invalidated when a secret is rotated?

The [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/ps-integration-lambda-extensions.html) states:

> the system detects parameter values that are used frequently and maintains them in the cache while clearing those that are expired or unused.

Does this mean when retrieving a secret using the `AWSCURRENT` version stage, if the secret value is updated, the value has expired and is thus cleared? Or is it solely in relation to the TTL (Time-to-live) settings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think about it this way: how would the lambda extension know there is a new value it should fetch instead of using the cached one? Only by checking the parameter store on each request which would defeat the purpose of the cache. Therefore it cannot know of any updates and will only fetch the updated value once the TTL expires.

The docs also cover that explicitly:

> **Changes to a parameter value before TTL expires**
> The extension doesn't detect changes to the parameter value and doesn't perform an auto-refresh before the TTL expires. If you change a parameter value, operations that use the cached parameter value might fail until the cache is next refreshed. If you expect frequent changes to a parameter value, we recommend setting a shorter TTL value.